# Change text of send button

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am currently on this website: www.emilfrolund.co/kontakt

I want to change the text of the "SEND COMMENT!" button to "Send Besked" (it's a Danish website, so I want the text to be Danish)

I am using Contact Form 7 in Wordpress, but it seems to be a problem with the Theme that I am currently using.

I want to know if there is a CSS command that I can insert that just changes the words "SEND COMMENT!" to "Send Besked" on a site-wide manner.

I know this is a long shot, and I know you guys don't like wordpress :D But It would be awesome if you could help!

If that one thing I asked about cannot be done, then how can I access the HTML page and edit it from there?

Best wishes,
Emil

This is the line of code I'd like to change

[image: line of code]

Comment: its emilfrolund.com/kontakt instead - typo.

Comment: Here is the line of code I would like to change http://imgur.com/a/iKuuD

Answer (score 0):

If the text is not hardcoded you can try to put this in your functions.php
Add as many words as you like

```
//* Change text
function myText( $translated, $original, $domain ) {
    $strings = array(
        'Send Comment' => 'Send Besked',
    );
    if ( isset( $strings[$original] ) ) {
        $translations = get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
        $translated = $translations->translate( $strings[$original] );
    }

    return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'myText', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Contact Form 7 as part of your theme and you have the correct admin access, the easiest way is to edit the form in the admin.

In the site's admin. Find 'Contact' in the left hand menu. It should have an envelope as its icon. Open it and you will be presented with a list of the forms available on your site.

In this list find the form you need to update and click the title to edit it.

Once on your form edit page there will be a tab title 'Form' it will probably be active and display the code for your form.

Towards the end of this you should have `[submit "SEND COMMENT!"]` change this to `[submit "Send Besked"]`

Then click save.

Comment: Hey - I already tried this, but it seems that it is an issue with the theme "Pure" that I am currently using. I went into the editor in wordpress and found the "SEND COMMENT!" under the comments.php file. This was when I started thinking it is something that the theme does.

Comment: I see, That's very annoying to override default editing like that. I had to see for my self and I stumbled across a comment in the thread below the download link. I've popped the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to contact forms list(1) from Contact menu then open your contact form in edit mode(2). Then find out the `[submit "SEND COMMENT!"]` and then change "SEND COMMENT!" text to "Send Besked" and finally save. That's it.

[1: Contact Forms List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Aw0.png)

[2: Contact Form Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5eCJ.png)

Comment: yea I already tried this, but it didnt work. It is some sort of theme based thing from the Pure theme that I am using, which makes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it has been hard coded into the theme's Js file  /js/theme.js on line 23 it has

```
Query('.temp_submit_cf7').html('<div class="shortcode_button btn_small btn_type5"><span class="ico_cont"><span class="ico_fader"></span><i class="ico_this icon-share-alt"></i></span><span class="btn_text">SEND COMMENT!</span></div>');
```

Substitute `SEND COMMENT!` for whatever you want.

Not ideal, and really only suitable if you are unlikely to change the text again.

Commenting out the entire line brings back the standard Contact Form 7 functionality, allowing you to change the button text in the editor, but the button styling goes, so if you are handy with your CSS that may be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks!! Thats awesome :)

Comment: Can I just say thank you once again - this did it! :) awesome!

Comment: np but don't forget to mark this as answered to help others who may come along wit a similar query.